# Xcode no longer shows 64-bit build option

Tags: xcode, macos, build, settings

I am trying to build a bundle linked to a static library for Unity3D. In searching for the ways to accomplish this, I somehow set my project to only build in 32 bit. I need to be able set it as 32 or 64 bit.

I have tried the obvious steps of making sure that the Architecture settings were either Normal (32/64 bit) or 64-bit Intel. No matter what changes I make, the only build option I receive is "My Mac 32-bit."

I am using Xcode 4.5

Comment: not sure but try with some other project. If problem persist, re-install XCode.